# Natbib, no space after prenote

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm using natbib for my bibliography. I'm using \citep[prenote][postnote]{reference} to cite reference.
By default, natbib will print a space between the prenote and the reference. But, I'm writting in french and I need to remove that space.

I found this to change the separator before the postnote :
\setcitestyle{notesep{}}
but it doesn't works for the prenote.

EXAMPLE :

What I want : (adapté d'Alain, 2015)

What I get : (adapté d' Alain, 2015)

my code : \citep[adapté d']{Alain2015}

Comment: Please provide a MWE with the syles you use. I am asking since the default is `notesep={, }` and you get a space.

Comment: How about `\newcommand\gobble[1]{}` and then `\citep[adapté d'\gobble][]{doody}`?

Answer (score 4):

The space is quite hardcoded, also I don't think that you will want to remove it in every prenote, so a command that resets locally the space is probably the best solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\nonatspace{%
 \let\oriNAT@spacechar\NAT@spacechar\def\NAT@spacechar{\let\NAT@spacechar\oriNAT@spacechar}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\citep[adapté d'][]{doody}

\citep[\nonatspace adapté d'][]{doody}

\citep[see][]{doody}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that this also removes the space between the comma and the year. So I get (adapté d'Alain,2015).

Comment: @Alain: You are right, I didn't thought about this. I edited the code.